# Visual Studio Code automatically deletes one tab when using a colon in an "elif"-statement

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Every time I use a colon in an `elif`-statement in Python, Visual Studio Code erases one tab.

For example:

```py
a ="fdiofdjiof"

if True:
    if a[10:] == "":
        pass
elif a[10:] == "":
```

That `elif` statement should have one tab more, but when I pressed 'Shift' + '.' (a colon on a QWERTZ keyboard), it automatically erased one tab. I think the bug only appears when using a colon in a string array selection.
Normally it should look like that:

[image: Picture of code]

I use Windows 10 Version 22H2, Visual Studio Code Version 1.78.2 (installed over official website, last stable Windows version, exe-file) and the Default Profile in VS code. None of the settings seems to be the reason for that problem.

I use the following extensions:

- Bookmarks v13.3.1
- C# v1.25.7
- Pylance v2023.5.30
- Python v2023.8.0

I tried that bug in a completly new file and it appeared every time.
Furthermore I tried to disable Python and Pylance extension, but that didn't help, either.

Comment: QWERTY user here, couldn't replicate the behavior on my side, so probably specific to QWERTZ. Probably obvious but I thought I would point it out.

Comment: I can replicate (QWERTY). Editor Tabs back as soon as I add the colon here `elif a[20:]`

Comment: Describe in detail the error you encountered and what you expected to be correct. Mark the tab in the code to remind everyone of the location or display the picture.

Comment: I can reproduce. My info: QWERTY keyboard, Ubuntu 22.04.2 with Xorg (not Wayland), VS Code 1.78.2 installed as Snap, Python extension v2023.8.0. What OS are you on, and how did you install VS Code?

Comment: curiously, it's a bit finicky. like- if I reindent with a different indentation width it seems to stop reproducing? (no idea why)

Comment: I updated the post with the requested information! Using different indentation width didn't stop the bug for me, but strangely enough sometimes the bug simply stops reproducing and then starts over appearing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, I found the problem. I disabled the second time Pylance and that time didn't forget to reload and restart VScode. Then the bug was gone. It seems really to be an Pylance bug.

I downgraded the Pylance version to v2022.11.30 and that seems to solve the problem.
Thanks for your help!

I will contact Microsoft to solve that bug in the next release.

Comment: If you report an issue on GitHub, don't forget to put the link here too.  glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as the answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Comment: @JialeDu Yeah, I won‘t forget. And now the answer is accepted, too :)